# DocumentDB paging by continue token not working well

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I working with documentDB `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client` version 1.11.0.0.
I try to make paging in my query, every time take the next 20 best results.
But if I have for example only 25 elements in my db, In the first call I received the first 20, in the next call when I call with the continue token I received again 20 results instead of 5 results.
My code is:

```
public static async Task<Tuple<List<Student>, string, int>> StudentSearch(string text, string continuationToken)
{
    List<Student> results = new List<Student>();
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(continuationToken))
        {
            FeedOptions options = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 20 };
            var userQuery = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<Student>(
           _uriStudentCollection, options).Where(x => x.StudentName.ToLower().Contains(text) || x.Description.ToLower().Contains(text)).OrderBy(x => x.Rank.TotalScore).AsDocumentQuery();
            var feedResponse = await userQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<Student>();
            foreach (var ad in feedResponse.AsEnumerable())
            {
                results.Add(ad);
            }
            string continuation = feedResponse.ResponseContinuation;
            return new Tuple<Student>, string, int>(results, continuation, results.Count);
        }
        else
        {
            FeedOptions feedOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 20, RequestContinuation = continuationToken };
            var userQuery = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<Student>(
           _uriStudentCollection, feedOptions).Where(x => x.StudentName.ToLower().Contains(text) || x.Description.ToLower().Contains(text)).OrderBy(x => x.Rank.TotalScore).AsDocumentQuery();

            var feedResponse = await userQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<Student>();
            foreach (var ad in feedResponse.AsEnumerable())
            {
                results.Add(ad);
            }
            string continuation = feedResponse.ResponseContinuation;
            return new Tuple<List<Student>, string, int>(results, continuation, results.Count);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it the same 20 or the final 5 plus 15 from the start again?

Answer (score 1):

I can't repro the issue on my side with you mentioned code. It seems that there is no issue in you mentioned code.

I test your code with [Microsoft.Azure.Documents](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/) Version **1.14.1** on my side, it works correctly.

[image]

If it is possible please have a try to update the [Microsoft.Azure.Documents](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/) to the lastest one. It seems that there is some redundance in your code. We could use the following code to replace it.

```
 public static async Task<Tuple<List<Student>, string, int>> StudentSearch( string text, string continuationToken = null)
        {
            var results = new List<Student>();
            FeedOptions options = new FeedOptions
            {
                MaxItemCount = 20
            };
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(continuationToken))
            {
                options.RequestContinuation = continuationToken;
            }
            var userQuery = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<Student>(
       _uriStudentCollection, feedOptions).Where(x => x.StudentName.ToLower().Contains(text) || x.Description.ToLower().Contains(text)).OrderBy(x => x.Rank.TotalScore).AsDocumentQuery();

            var feedResponse = await userQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<Student>();
            foreach (var ad in feedResponse.AsEnumerable())
            {
               results.Add(ad);
            }
            string continuation = feedResponse.ResponseContinuation;
            return new Tuple<List<Student>, string, int>(results, continuation, results.Count);
         }
```